# Differential Equation. VERY small problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to ask a question later, after I show you this

TESTING:
x^2 = 1
Differentiate both sides
2x = 0

TESTING:
x = 1
Differentiate both sides
dx/dx = 0
1 = 0

So when can I differentiate both sides? Perhaps I just need to understand the basics of differentiation.. May someone explain please? Thanks!

Comment: No. You should say $2xdx=0$ and $dx=0$. When you are going to take a derivative at one point, you need a function and the neighborhood of that point. But what you mentioned is finding the changes of both sides of an equation, not the derivative of function with respect to a variable.

Comment: If x=1, it is a constant and its derivative is 0. The same applies to your first example.

Comment: You have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ with $f(x) = g(x)$ somewhere. It's not necessarily true that $f'(x) = g'(x)$ there too. Take $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = -x$. Then they are equal at $x = 0$ but $f'(x) = 1$ and $g'(x) = -1$ at all points, so they are not equal.